# ActiveMQ cluster discovery on Openshift v3 / Kubernetes

Tags: activemq-classic, kubernetes, openshift-origin

ActiveMQ built-in [cluster discovery mechanisms](http://activemq.apache.org/discovery.html) are basically based on multicast (excepting LDAP here).

Openshift v3 / Kubernetes don't support well multicast as it could be quite bad or misfunctioning on a public cloud infrastructure.

Is there any existing option to enable network of activemq brokers discovery within Openshift v3 ?

I saw the project [jboss-openshift/openshift-ping](https://github.com/jboss-openshift/openshift-ping) enabling discovery for JGroups members on Openshift. I am looking for an equivalent for ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 1):

fabric8 is a project that has a number of value-adds for OS3 / kubernetes platforms

- http://fabric8.io/

There is *clustered* ActiveMQ out of the box

- http://fabric8.io/guide/fabric8MQ.html

As the project is in development, you may get best help on irc chat on #fabric8 on freenode - all the guys hang out there.